# How to align text in a fraction and write it in an equation format in latex

Tags: latex

I have a fraction with only text in it as follows:

[image]
I have done the following:

```
\[
\text{R\_{score}} = \frac{\begin{aligned}
      \text{Sample text for numerator with 2 rows} \\ \text{row 2 of numerator which isn't aligned with first row}
      \end{aligned}}%
  {\text{Sample text for denominator}}
\]
```

Firstly, I don't know how to fit it within the two column width. And also, I am struggling to align the text in the numerator in a prettier way.
And I cannot get it to behave like an equation so that I get the "(2)" next to it.

Please help.Thank you!

Comment: Please make a compilable [mre]